# Using GET parameters with Django and Ionic

Tags: django, rest, ionic-framework, django-rest-framework, postman

I'm developing an application where I need to make HTTP requests, so I'm trying to use the GET method with parameters.

My code in ionic is this:

```
getZona(code: string) {
 return this.http.get(
   this.API_URL + "zonas", {codigo_acceso: code}, {}
 );
}
```

My Django code is

```
class ZonaView(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
 queryset = Zona.objects.all()
 serializer_class = ZonaSerializer
```

So when I do a GET request, I get all records, even though if the parameter's value doesn't exists in the records. No matter what I write in the parameter, I get all records.

I have tried with postman and I get the same behavior.

Hope you can help me.

Comment: I hope you should have to go through the [DRF filtering](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/filtering/) doc first

Comment: Also, you can make use of this awesome package [django-filter](https://django-filter.readthedocs.io/en/stable/)